# How to map query string RequestBody to POJO with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hi all here is what my code looks like:

the Spring Controller class

```
public class CarDataController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test(@ModelAttribute CarData carData) {
      /** how do I get carData? **/
    }
}
```

When I cast the @RequestBody to a string I get

```
carType=Ford&carColour=green
```

The encoding type is

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

This does not work. There is a 4xx response generated. I'm wondering what I need to do in order to get carData instantiated correctly.

**Update**

thanks to user chrylis I was able to resolve it. Here is the updated code.

the Spring Controller class

```
public class CarDataController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test(@RequestBody final CarData carData) {
      /** how do I get carData? **/
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Spring Boot. I do not have Jackson configured. Is that the first step?

Comment: Try using `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`.

Comment: By the way, it's helpful if you'll describe *what happens*--you just asked "how do I get" without an explanation of what's going wrong. Presumably you got a `CarData` with null values, but if you're getting some other behavior, that would be relevant.

Comment: yep that did it. thanks. wish I had come on here sooner.

Comment: FWIW, searching for "Spring RequestBody application/x-www-form-urlencoded" yielded the question I'm going to close as duplicate for.